# Regular expression for all a* except aa?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I'm stumped on how you would describe a language which is a* except for aa, so the following is acceptable:

```
a
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
...
```

It's for part of the below DFA
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A word consisting of $n \neq 2$ many $a$s either consists of zero $a$s, or of a single $a$, or of at least three many $a$s.

Comment: ohhh so (empty) + a + aaaa* would cover those

Comment: Right, that's the solution.